# Can't edit files after I run the composer-update command

Tags: php, laravel

I create a project using this command (within htdocs):

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel my-project --prefer-dist
```

Then I update the storage folder so that the site can run:

```
chmod -R 777 my-project/app/storage
```

But then when I go to edit any of the files it asks me to enter my Mac OSX password. I then need to `chmod` the app folder as well but this doesn't seem correct.

How can I get it setup so that when I run the create-project command, the files are writable by my user? Or is this normal for laravel projects?

(I'm fine with running that command on the storage folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use sudo to create the project, sudo creates the project as the root user.  If you can't do that with htdocs, you need to change the ownership of htdocs using `sudo chown <you>:<group> <path to htdocs>`. This will allow you to create a project with your user credentials.

After this the only reason you might need to change the storage folder permissions/ownership is because your webserver will need access

Comment: Thanks for the response! I chowned the htdocs folder to myuser:daemon (the group my xampp runs as) but I still get a permission denied error. <code> [ErrorException]                          
  touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied  </code>

Comment: I get these errors:
<pre>
file_put_contents(/Users/myuser/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$security-core.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
<pre>

Comment: @therookie sorry been away. You are getting some issues because the cache for composer was created by a sudo try this `sudo chown -R <you>:<group> /Users/myuser/.composer/cache/`.  I sometime get the -R confused with -r so if you get an error try changing that.